# UWSim: Simulating RADAR using Multibeam Sensor

Tags: ros, sensor, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to simulate a radar sensor in UWSim environment. I know that it is somehow possible using the `multibeam` sensor facility, but I would like to get some more ideas about how this could be achieved. Basically I want to get the distances of obstacles from the boat, and I want to do this with a radar mentality. Send rays and get the distances.

```
<multibeamSensor>
      <name>multibeam</name>
      <relativeTo>part0</relativeTo>
      <position>
        <x> -1.5 </x>
        <y> 0 </y>
        <z> 0 </z>
      </position>  
      <orientation>
        <r>0</r>
        <p>1.57</p>
        <y>0 </y>
      </orientation>
      <initAngle>-60</initAngle>
      <finalAngle>60</finalAngle>
      <angleIncr>0.1</angleIncr>
      <range>50</range>
</multibeamSensor>
```

How should I use the multibeam sensor facility in order to achieve this? Is there a way to visualize the rays, so that I can verify that I am not doing something odd?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211169/uwsim:-simulating-radar-using-multibeam-sensor/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Multibeam sensor provides the distance of obstacles from the sensor. You can visualize the rays using the visible tag "1" just after  relativeTo tag. Unfortunately this feature is not in the deb packages yet (next version), so you need to use UWSim from source. You should see something like this (right image is a zoom):

[image: multibeam debug]

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1